# PixiJS - Absorbing Light and Dynamic Audio based on Location

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, pixi.js

I want to create a game where lighting and sound is curcial. I need directional lights that can be blocked by objects e.g. walls or other players (dynamically obviously). It seems like I want to have something like this [image]

Is this possible with PixiJS ? If so - how ? I currently do not understand how this is supposed to be implemented. I guess [this](https://pixijs.io/pixi-lights/docs/PIXI.lights.DirectionalLight.html) is a start - but how do you block or absorb the light?

Futhermore:
I need dynamic audio. So the volume needs to decrease the futher its source is away (optional: audio volume coud be decreased by objects e.g. walls)

Is this possible with PIXIJS ?

If its not possible with pixijs ? Is there a similar lib, that can do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution for me was implementing a ray casting algorithm.

I would strongly recommend visiting [redblobgames visibility tutorial](https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/).

Or check out [sight and light](https://ncase.me/sight-and-light/).

I also implemented [the pixijs.sound package](https://pixijs.io/pixi-sound/docs/PIXI.sound.filters.StereoFilter.html) and used the stereo filter to create some kind of "dynamic" or "directional" audio.